# HTML first line goes to bottom

Tags: html

Using Pycharm

```
hello world
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static './cafe.jpg' %}"
```

When you execute the code, '**Hello world**' goes to the bottom as shown in the picture.

[excuted img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUeF5.jpg)

How can I lift it up??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using inline CSS using the position and top attributes we can change the position of the text.

```
<h1 style='position:absolute;top:0'>hello world</h1>
```

[executed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Unoan.jpg)

Comment: Is it impossible to raise it up without being included in the picture?